# How to load specific javascript from a common javascript based on URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multi-domain .NET platform that uses a common `CustomJSFunctions` file to load customizations that occur when the document is ready. Certain functions/variables apply to certain domains and some of them conflict. I want to split the `CustomJSFunctions` file into domain specific files that are loaded based on the URL.

The `CustomJSFunctions` file could contain something like this:

```
var url = document.location.href;
if (url.search("urltext") > 0) {
    $.getScript("some.js");
}
else if (url.search("moreurltext") > 0) {
    $.getScript("someother.js");
}
else {
    $.getScript("athird.js");
}
```

which I've tried, but it doesn't work. I don't have the ability to manually add another `script` tag to the `head`. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at require.js - http://requirejs.org/

Comment: What you are doing should work, assuming you're keeping dependencies intact.

Comment: "...it doesn't work." Can you elaborate? Any error? Perhaps some code that depends on one of these scripts is executing before the script is loaded. Do `$.getScript("some.js", function() { console.log('loaded'); });`

Comment: It's working now. I had to tweak the path in getScript.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
if (url.search("urltext") > 0) {
    $('head').append('<script src="some.js"></script>');


//etc.
```

You could even append it to the end of the `body` if you wanted.